# Catching ⌘+1 in Safari JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I'm writing a Safari 6 extension which adds a few keyboard shortcuts. One of the things I'd like to do is catch when the user presses ⌘+1 ⌘+2, etc. Right now, Safari seems to not fire any event when this happens. Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xe9YQ/ to show the code, and here's the JS:

```
$( 'body' ).bind( 'keypress', function ( event ) {

  var modifier = '';
  if ( event.metaKey ) {
    modifier += 'cmd-';
  }
  if ( event.ctrlKey ) {
    modifier += 'ctrl-';
  }
  if ( event.altKey ) {
    modifier += 'alt-';
  }
  if ( event.shiftKey ) {
    modifier += 'shift-';
  }

  $( 'body' ).html( modifier + event.keyCode );
});
```

If you try "⌘+j", "⌘+t", or even "⌘+0" and "⌘+shift+5" you'll see correct output. From this, it seems that it's not a problem of overriding browser shortcuts, and not a problem of using the numerical row.

Is anyone familiar with this problem? Is this a known bug? I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: for posterity, is there a word for what the "⌘" key is called?

Comment: Perhaps this is captured by the browser or by the OS? Tab-switching, perhaps?

Comment: Note that most key combinations don't fire for me either (Chrome/Win7).

Comment: @jbabey Sorry, I suppose I should have said "cmd" or "command".

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `keydown` event in combination with `preventDefault()`, because <kbd>⌘</kbd> combinations may have bindings already (in Chrome, for example <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> switches to the first tab).

```
$( 'body' ).bind( 'keydown', function ( event ) {
    var modifier = '';
    if ( event.metaKey ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      modifier += 'cmd-';
    }
    if ( event.ctrlKey ) {
      modifier += 'ctrl-';
    }
    if ( event.altKey ) {
      modifier += 'alt-';
    }
    if ( event.shiftKey ) {
      modifier += 'shift-';
    }
    $( 'body' ).html( modifier + event.keyCode );
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. The event for ⌘+0 does not fire correctly in the first place, so there's nothing to work with. It seems more likely that I need to listen for a different event, or attach the listener to another object.

Comment: Running that fiddle on my computer has the same result. Pressing ⌘+3 or ⌘+4 does not correctly update the body. Is this perhaps a problem with my computer?

Comment: I guess it depends on the browser. I was testing in Chrome, now I tested in Safari and it didn't work. My bad.

Comment: Some shortcuts just can't be prevented by `.preventDefault()` (by design). For example, on Chrome/Win7 I can get it to handle Ctrl+A and Ctrl+F correctly, but it won't stop Ctrl+W and Ctrl+N. Firefox on the other hand prevents all of them.